# Wait for all other actions on a PR to complete before continuing

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request, dependabot

I essentially want all other workflows to complete before continuing and action. I'm running the workflow which requires all others to be done on a PR, and I'm using it for a dependabot automerge workflow.

I've tried [Wait for Check](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/wait-for-check) but it only works consistently on singular workflows.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not about JavaScript per se. Please only use the `javascript` tag if you have a question about JavaScript code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this publicly accessible ["wait for workflows" action from Chainlink](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-github-actions/tree/main/utils/wait-for-workflows) that waits either for all workflows or only for the specified ones, and then run your job.